# Why does MongoDB produce invalid JSON? The ObjectId is not quoted, breaks jq parser

Tags: json, mongodb

I've searched the forum and seen many folks with a similar problem, but not this exact one.

I think my question is the simplest form, and there must be something I'm missing because no one is asking it.

I have a shell script that calls a MongoDB script and gets the results in a file.  I then want to parse that file with jq.

jq is breaking because the output from the query is not valid JSON.  The offender is the ObjectId.  I'm at a total loss as to how something that's "ALL JSON ALL THE TIME" produces invalid JSON.

I'm pretty sure there's something fundamental that I'm missing.

I have a file called MyMongoScript.js.  Its contents look like this:

```
db.WorkflowJobs.find().sort({"STATUS":1}).forEach(printjson)
```

I call MyMongScript.js with the following command:

```
mongo -u $MONGO_U -p $MONGO_P $MONGO_DB -quiet --eval "var DATE_TO_RUN=\"$DATE_TO_RUN\"" MyMongoScript.js
```

Here's the results to STDOUT:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52816fd50bc9efc3e6d8e33f"),
"WORK_TYPE" : "HIVE",
"Script_Name" : "upload_metrics_LANDING_to_HIST.sql",
"Stop_On_Fail" : true,
"STATUS" : "READY",
"START_TS" : "NULL",
"END_TS" : "NULL",
"DURATION" : "NULL",
"INS_TS" : "Mon Nov 11 2013 16:01:25 GMT-0800 (PST)"
}
```

Here's what jsonlint.com says about it:

```
Parse error on line 2:
{    "_id": ObjectId("52816fd50b
------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Post the JSON you get back here, not a picture on an external host.

Comment: because MongoDB isn't JSON, it is BSON? ObjectId is a BSON object, try using `toJSON()` on your results

Comment: I've never had the `ObjectID` pulled out with it like that, normally it returned `_id : "3453454354325436asadsa"` something like that..

Comment: Working on it guys.... sorry..  can't figure out code block.  Give me 5.

Comment: Where do you get that? Most drivers should show the objectid in its full form

Comment: Ok I didn't see that you actually printjson, can you show your entire code?

Comment: When you say entire code, what do you mean?  Do you want to see my call to MongoDB?

Comment: Sorry, I mean what's `printjson`? It has to be a callback so I think there might be something wrojng there

Comment: @Sammaye It's a default, built-in Mongo shell function that... prints JSON, almost.

Comment: @DaveNewton not the way he was using it...

Comment: @Sammaye How do you figure?! Works just fine the way he's using it: `forEach` takes a function reference.

Comment: @DaveNewton there is a difference between `function(doc){ printJson(doc); }` and `printjson` for all I know anything could have been in that callback, like a secret code to travel through time.

Comment: @Sammaye No, there isn't, at least no meaningful one... The `printjson` reference means that `printjson` will be called for each object in the result. How is an immediate function that calls `printjson` for each object in the result any different?

Comment: @DaveNewton Cos I can't read minds? I can't solve a problem I cannot see the full extent of. The answer below was a guess and that was after my first comment which did actually sovle the problem

Comment: @Sammaye No mind-reading necessary, `printjson` is `printjson`, regardless of how it's being used between those two chocies. It dumps out things like `ISODate` and `ObjectID` as invalid JSON, they need to be converted to be processed by JSON tools.

Comment: @DaveNewton `printjson` is a variable here with reference to either a function or value, how do you know what's in `printjson`?

Comment: @Sammaye Because (a) it's a default mongo shell function, and (b) OP is using it to print JSON?

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough I didn't know javascript can actually work the way you was saying it seems it can

Comment: @Sammaye A function is a function. If you leave off the parens it's a function reference. A function reference is the "same" as an immediate function. Simply trying it would show this to be true.

Comment: @DaveNewton my understanding was that javascript specifically required an anon function, I never tried it since I find the syntax actually confusing to other programmers etc as such that is why only now I have

Comment: @Sammaye Passing around function references is one of the *main* ways JS is used. Using anonymous functions ends up creating bulky, deeply-nested code, and makes those functions *impossible* to test in isolation since they only exist as part of something else. I'd rethink.

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant I thought the `forEach` function took only a anon function

Comment: @Sammaye It takes a function reference, whether it's an anonymous function or a reference--they're the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for your MyMongoScript.js:

```
db.WorkflowJobs.find().sort({"STATUS":1}).forEach(function(myDoc){myDoc._id=myDoc._id.valueOf();print(tojson(myDoc))});
```

The key is `valueOf()` which will set your ObjectId to a String.

**EDITED** Left out a paren.

Comment: Dude you nailed it.  I can't thank you enough for taking the time to post a working fix.  The two dudes who commented on my question, bless their hearts were full of very fast and very meaningless info.  Guys I don't mean that to be offensive, just critical.

Comment: Also, I found a different workaround that I will post below.  Though what I found works, I like your solution better because it's much more portable.

Comment: @MattR It might look meaningless to you, but take note of Sammaye comment about BSON vs. JSON as it is the root of your problem

Comment: It isn't completely correct though because you shouldn't need to explicitly convert the _id like that, instead just do `printjson(myDoc)`

Comment: @Sammaye Unfortunately printjson(myDoc) doesn't do the ObjectId->String conversion (using MongoDB v2.4.5 at least, my currently installed version.) That's the equivalent of what the OP had tried already.